# Activity becoming unresponsive after dismissing Google mobile ad

Tags: android, mobile, webview, interstitial

I'm using `Google Mobile Ads SDK` to display an InterstitialAd in my Activity. The activity has just one `WebView` that displays HTML5 content. After dismissing the ad, occasionally on some devices the `WebView`/`Activity` becomes unresponsive... Any ideas on how I can fix this or why it happens?

Comment: Try looking at the Android log when this happens.

Comment: I don't see anything that looks related to the issue... The only thing that I do see in the log is:  `SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]  
03-04 15:07:44.373    3347-3374/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - `       this appears only on the device that has this issue...  @DavidChristopherReynolds

Comment: and also: `E/chromium﹕ external/chromium/net/disk_cache/entry_impl.cc:905: [0304/151812:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(905)] Failed to save user data` which actually could be related since I'm trying to load a `WebView`, but I don't get why this error happens....

Comment: I see this error in the log: `Ads﹕ JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined` Is it possible that it's the ad content that's causing the issue?

Comment: It may well be. If there is an uncaught exception in the ad, and if the ad is running in your activity, then it will crash your activity as well.

Comment: BTW, you can use an UncaughtExceptionHandler to catch these kind of problems. Assign it like this: Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler(this); in your activity's OnCreate.